# Junit Tagging in Selenium webdriver doesn't work

Tags: java, selenium, junit, webdriver

I'm using Selenium Webdriver with cucumber, gherkin and java. I am tagging all my scenario's: @website, @wip, @disabled etc.

When I want to use a junit runner to create certain testsets, it always runs ALL the tests, regardless of what scenario is tagged.

What I got in my junit runner is this:

```
package com.website;

import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    format = "pretty",
    tags = {"@Regression,@Functional","~@wip"},
    features="src/test/resources"
)
public class Runner {}
```

The scenario's and the feature file look somewhat like this:

```
# language: nl

Functionality: This is a feature file

 @wip
 Scenario: stuff-001: As a user, I want stuff
 Given When I do something
 If I click somewhere
 Then I can see something

 @Regression
 Scenario: stuff-002: As a user, I want stuff again
 Given When I do something
 If I click somewhere
 Then I can see something

 @Functional
 Scenario: stuff-003: As a user, I want stuff once more
 Given When I do something
 If I click somewhere
 Then I can see something
```

I want my runner to run just scenario 2 and 3 (tagged with @Regression and @Functional respectively), and skip scenario 1 (that's why it's tagged with @wip). However, when I run the junit runner, it just runs both scenario 1, 2 and any other in any other feature.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a quotes after @Regression, try things mention as below and it should work.

```
package com.website;

        import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
        import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        format = "pretty",
        tags = {"@Regression","@Functional","~@wip"},
        features="src/test/resources"
)
public class Runner {}
```

Comment: Alas, still the same: All tests are being run, whether they have the @wip tags or not. It seems like it doesn't even glance at the tags at the scenario's...

Comment: Actually this answer is not correct.
`"@Regression, @Functional"` means Regression OR Functional and `"@Regression", "@Functional"` means Regression AND Functional.

The problem is with JUnit runner (I don't know what exactly is wrong)

Comment: @RafałLaskowski is it safe to say that my dependencies are correct, as it does actually run something? Or could it be that I need to puzzle that out?

Comment: @user3356141 I am not sure. Does your feature file contains keywoard `Feature:`? Does it have correct extension `.feature`? Did you mark any of your tests with JUnit tags like `@Test`?

Comment: @RafałLaskowski The feature file needs to contain the keyword Feature? What do you mean by that? The extension is correct though, and the JUnit Tags are in place and are not giving any errors...

Comment: Example: `Feature: Log in` and then `Scenario: I should be able to log in with valid credentials`.

Do you use Eclipse? You can download extensions to support natural language processors